# как изменить цвет шаблона при нажатии на кнопку xaml ?

Tags: xaml, uwp

```
 <Style x:Key="roungButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="80"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Name="OuterRing" Width ="80" Height ="80" Fill="DarkGreen"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Pressed">
                                <VisualState >
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="OuterRing" Value="Red"/> 
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: А какой смысл изменения цвета? В зависимости от этого правильно по-разному.

Comment: ну, необходимо, чтобы изначально эллипс был прозрачным, а по нажатию на кнопку - заливался каким-либо цветом. хочу сделать круглую кнопку, как в скайп UWP в беседах

Comment: а какой смысл нажатия на кнопку? что происходит с точки зрения логики программы (а не с точки зрения того, как выглядит интерфейс)?

Comment: да ничего особого, просто отправляется сообщение, и всё. а
весь код который я находил - для wpf, он в UWP не работает

Comment: Не-не, давайте о смысле. Прозрачность кнопки означает, что нету набранного сообщения?

Comment: нет. смысл просто в красивостях, к бизнес логике привязки вообще никакой нет. таких кнопок должно быть вообще 5 - 6, каждая с разными действиями

Comment: Вы уверены, что нету? Обычно кнопка своим цветом что-то говорит юзеру, и её состояние можно привязать к свойству из VM

Comment: да, абсолютно. вы скайпом универсальным пользовались ? 
вот там просто кнопка подсвечивается при нажатии, показывая, что пользователь действительно нажал именно на неё, а не куда - то мимо. может, как-то при помощи сторибоардов сделать ?

Comment: А, понял! То есть при нажатии, и потом сразу назад? Если да, то это ж анимация.

Comment: да-да, именно так. не подскажете, как это реализовать ?

Comment: Я попробую. У меня нет опыта с UWP, зато есть опыт с анимациями. Напишу ответ, когда соображу.

Comment: спасибо заранее

Comment: Готово, пробуйте.

Comment: спасибо, помогло  !

Comment: Пожалуйста! Спрашивайте ещё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось вот так:

```
<Style x:Key="RoundButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="80"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Name="OuterRing" Width ="80" Height ="80" Fill="DarkGreen"/>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="OuterRing.Fill" Value="LightGray"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="OuterRing.Fill" Value="DarkGreen"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="OuterRing.Fill" Value="DarkKhaki"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="OuterRing.Fill" Value="Red"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Если хотите красивее, с анимациями, то нужно вместо

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Target="OuterRing.Fill" Value="Red"/>
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

использовать

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <VisualState.Storyboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" To="Red"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="OuterRing"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState.Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```